# Redirect specific page to different domain keeping language but including a default language

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How to redirect something like this (from one domain to another keeping only the same language):

```
RewriteRule ^(de|en|es|fr|it)/folder1/file.html$  http://domain.com/folder3/en/folder2/some_file [R=302,L]
```

The above rule will work if I want to redirect any of the languages in the brackets to one language which is EN. What I would like to do is to redirect to the same language but only for the first 3 languages (**de|en|es**). The last two languages (**fr|it**) should redirect to **EN** instead.

I can write one entry for each language as below:

```
RewriteRule ^de/folder/file.html$  http://domain.com/folder3/de/folder2/some_file [R=302,L]
```

But listing the languages separately in this way doesn't seem to be good coding or efficient, because I'd have to repeat the above line for all 5 languages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the match you have captured in parentheses in the substitution string by using `$1` (for the first parenthesised match in the pattern), `$2` (for the second match), and so on.

Hence you can write what you want in two rules. It's a bit of duplication but not as much as you'd require if you did all 5 languages separately.

```
RewriteRule ^(de|en|es)/folder1/file.html$  http://domain.com/folder3/$1/folder2/some_file [R=302,L]
RewriteRule ^(fr|it)/folder1/file.html$ http://domain.com/folder3/en/folder2/some_file [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I think this is not what I need because if I do in ex. `www.domain2.net/de/folder1/file.html` it should go to `domain.com/folder3/de/folder2/some_file` but this won't work referring to your answer.

Comment: Your example `www.domain2.net/de/folder1/file.html` correctly redirects to `domain.com/folder3/de/folder2/some_file` for me. What are you experiencing instead?

Comment: you're right, it's working. I had internal server error before, I've even tried your way before my post but because that error I've thought that I was doing something wrong, but now as you confirmed that this is good way, I've found a bug in my code. Thank you for reply.